# jqgrid column chooser returns column order based on current order not original order

Tags: jqgrid

I want to persist the column order via localStorage which is working. However, the column chooser gives the order of the columns based on the current order not the original order.

Example:

3 column table where 0 is first, 1 == second, 2 is last column

0,1,2

choose column order to put last column in first, order becomes

2,0,1

choose column order again and put (original last column) back into last and order becomes:

1,2,0

because it resets the column numbers based on current order rather than ORIGINAL order. How to fix this?

```
onClickButton: function () {
      $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser', {
        done : function (perm) {
          if (perm) {
            localStorage["OD_Table_Col_Order"] = perm;
            $(this).jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
          }
        }       
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can find the solution if you would use `remapColumns` parameter of jqGrid as additional information.

One more way would be to save in `localStorage` the array of `name` properties of `colModel` items instead of the indexes `perm`.